# Fire TextChanged event of dynamic textbox doesnt work

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, textbox, postback

I created a Gridview whose cells has a textbox each one. The textbox`s has been dinamically created in the code-behind. I assign the event TextChange to the control but never fired.

I have two goals solving this, to catch the textchanged event of each one of the textbox's to evaluate it, and on the other hand, get the textbox's text after the user press a button "save".

I tried to get the control on a button postback, but after a postback, the 'cell.Controls' has no results. So why the textbox`s are disappearing?

I tried to create a WithEvents (Public WithEvents txtBoxEv As TextBox) to set it to the event header but the event didnt fire

```vb
'Here im creating the control into a method of code-behind (not the _Load event), and assign the event
For i = 1 To e.Row.Cells.Count - 1

      Dim txtbox As New TextBox
      txtbox.ID = "txtData" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString + i.ToString
      txtbox.MaxLength = 17
      txtbox.CssClass = "txtBoxCells"
      AddHandler txtbox.TextChanged, AddressOf TextBox1_TextChanged
      e.Row.Cells(i).Controls.Add(txtbox)
Next

'This is the event
Protected Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

End Sub
```

After many attempts and investigation im tired to test, but im unable to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of the event handler seems to be incomplete.

Please try:

```
Protected Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles txtbox.TextChanged
```

Comment: Its true, the event is firing with the Handles. But the problem loosing dynamics controls on postback persists. Maybe its better to open another question with this particular problem or change the title of this one.